# React + TypeScript error: No overload matches this call

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am receiving a massive error when mapping through an array like:

```
// Home.tsx

  render() {
    const { inputs, outputs, expectedOutputs } = this.state;
    return (
        <ContentContainer>
          {inputs.map((input, i) => {
            return (
              <TestRow
                key={i}
                rowNumber={i}
                xml={inputs[i].xml}
                desc={inputs[i].desc}
                output={outputs[i]}
                expectedOutput={expectedOutputs[i]}
                handleTextAreaUpdate={this.handleTextAreaUpdate}
              />
            );
          })}
        </ContentContainer>
    );
```

```
// TestRow.tsx

interface TestRowProps {
  xml: string;
  desc: string;
  output: string;
  expectedOutput: string;
  rowNumber: number;
}

class TestRow extends Component<TestRowProps, {}> {
  textArea: any;
```

the error is:

No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: Readonly): TestRow', gave the following error.

```
    Type '{ key: number; rowNumber: number; xml: string; desc: string; output: never; expectedOutput: string; handleTextAreaUpdate: (e: { target: { value: string; }; }, column: number, rowNumber: number) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TestRow> & Readonly<TestRowProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'handleTextAreaUpdate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TestRow> & Readonly<TestRowProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: TestRowProps, context?: any): TestRow', gave the following error.
    Type '{ key: number; rowNumber: number; xml: string; desc: string; output: never; expectedOutput: string; handleTextAreaUpdate: (e: { target: { value: string; }; }, column: number, rowNumber: number) => void; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TestRow> & Readonly<TestRowProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'.
      Property 'handleTextAreaUpdate' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<TestRow> & Readonly<DiagramProps> & Readonly<{ children?: ReactNode; }>'
```

.  TS2769

Comment: `Property 'handleTextAreaUpdate' does not exist on type` means that your component `TestRow` does not expect a prop called `handleTextareaUpdate`

Comment: Please provide implementation of `TestRow`. It seems that it doesn't have any props at all.

Comment: updated to include interface

Comment: @yadejo do i need to add that prop to interface?

Comment: It seems `handleTextAreaUpdate` does not exist on whatever the render function is attached to.

Comment: Where is `handleTextAreaUpdate` defined?

Comment: Sorry guys, I'm really tired and messed up when showing relationship between Home.tsx and TestRow.tsx. @jperl handleTextAreaUpdate is defined in Home.tsx

Answer (score 26, accepted):

in the error message, you can find the problem. `Property 'handleTextAreaUpdate' does not exist on type` means that you should define a property for `handleTextAreaUpdate` in the `TestRowProps` interface.

Comment: `handleTextAreaUpdate: Function` at least gets rid of the error

Comment: Had the same problem with the Button component from Material UI. It was not accepting ```component``` property because looks like it was not declared. This solved the issue (added component property to the ```Buton.d.ts```): 

    ```component?: Function;```

Comment: @klevisx when you say you "added to Buton.d.ts" are you talking about the core library or a different file you had?

Comment: @HelmutGranda I am talking about the core library. This is not ideal though, but it will work. Maybe you can create your own button based on this file and import it always locally rather than from MUI.

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing the `return` inside the function. I had the same issue, but realized the export function didn't have any `return`.